# Отсчет времени(дней на сайте)

Tags: php, дата, время

Как сделать отсчет времени (дней) на сайте, при этом каждые семь дней автообновление отсчета ?
ЕстьКод:

```
function downcounter($date){
    $check_time = strtotime($date) - time();
    if($check_time <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    $days = floor($check_time/86400);
    $hours = floor(($check_time%86400)/3600);
    $minutes = floor(($check_time%3600)/60);
    $seconds = $check_time%60;
    $str = $days;


return $str;
```

}

```
//$nextWeek = date("Y-m-d",time()+7*24*60*60);
//$timer = downcounter($nextWeek);

 $timer = downcounter('2013-02-19 23:59:59');
```

Похоже нужно делать БД и хранить дату там и если текущая системная дата == дате из БД, то выполнить: time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) - и записать новую дату в БД . ВОПРОС: Как сделать без БД, не хочу делать БД ради одной функции. ??

Comment: А может просто ориентироваться на текущий день недели и расчитывать не на 7 дней а скажем до ближайшей пятницы ?

Comment: Отличная идея. Подскажите плиз, как изменить код чтобы оно работало через дни недели. Буду очень-очень благодарен.

Comment: date('w') даст текущий день недели, 0 - воскресенье, 1 - понедельник и т.д. корректируем его до нашего календаря, т.е. 0 меняем на 7 и находим разницу в днях до требуемого дня недели

Comment: Обновил ответ. добавил функцию для пересчета.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php (Секция format)

```
<?php
   $datetime = new DateTime();
   echo $datetime->format('w');
   echo $datetime->format('N');
```

А там можно пересчитать относительно дня недели.

```
<?php

    function daysTo($dayOfWeek)
    {
        $delta = (integer) date('N') - $dayOfWeek;
        //Что бы промежуток был 0 - 6
        return $delta > 0 ? 7 - $delta : -$delta;
        // Что бы промежуток был 1 - 7
        // return $delta >= 0 ? 7 - $delta : -$delta;
    }

    echo daysTo(1) . PHP_EOL; // Понедельник
    echo daysTo(2) . PHP_EOL; // Вторник
    echo daysTo(3) . PHP_EOL; // Среда
    echo daysTo(4) . PHP_EOL; // Четверг
    echo daysTo(5) . PHP_EOL; // Пятница
    echo daysTo(6) . PHP_EOL; // Суббота
    echo daysTo(7) . PHP_EOL; // Воскресенье
```